# CSS - List with numbers in circles in IE11

Tags: html, css, list, internet-explorer

[Browser Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ7L7.png)

Hi
I'm working on a site where I need to add numbers in a circle in a list. I've copied this code which I'm testing as it's pretty much the type of look I'm after, and it works fine in every browser except IE11, which unfortunately is one of the browsers I have to ensure the site will work with. The image above shows this working in Chrome on the left, and IE11 on the right.

I can't figure out why this isn't working. When I view in IE11 all the the numbers disappear. Can anyone help point me in the right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.au {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #888;
  padding:10px; 
  margin:50px;
}
ol {
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset:mycounter;
  padding:0;
}
ol li {
  position:relative; 
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding:5px 0;
}
ol li:before {
  content:counter(mycounter); 
  counter-increment:mycounter;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-30px;
  width:25px;height:25px;line-height:25px;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#fff;
  background:teal;
  text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="au">
<h2>States in Australia</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>New South Wales</li>
      <li>Victoria</li>
      <li>South Australia</li>
      <li>Western Australia</li>
      <li>Queensland</li>      
      <li>Tasmania</li>      
    </ol>
<h2>Territories in Australia</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Northern Territory</li>
      <li>Australian Capital Territory</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g1Lsnw7v/ with your code work nice in IE11

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Unable to replicate in IE11. The fiddle above works fine.

Comment: Yes, this does work in jsfiddle viewing in IE11. Strange, when I load the html file directly into IE11 it doesn't work, all of the numbers in the circles disappear. I might check this on a different computer see if it works. My doctype  <!DOCTYPE html> should be fine for IE11?